# E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "String::String", соответствующие списку аргументов

Tags: c++, строки, классы, char

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << "Hello World!\n";

String str("HELLO");

cout << str;

return 0;
}
```

String.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class String
{
private:
    char* str;
    int length;
public:
    String();
    String(char* str);
    String(const String& other);
    String(String&& other) noexcept;
    ~String();
    String& operator= (const String& other);
    String& operator+ (const String& other);
    char& operator[] (size_t i) const;
    friend bool operator== (const String& str, const String& other);
    friend bool operator!= (const String& str, const String& other);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const String& other)
    {
        return (out << other.str);
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(ostream& in, const String& other)
    {
        return (in >> other.str);
    }
    size_t Length();
    void show();
};
```

String.cpp

```
#include "String.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

String::String()
{
    str = nullptr;
    length = 0;
}

String::String(char* str)
{
    length = strlen(str);
    this->str = new char[length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        this->str[i] = str[i];

    this->str[length] = '\0';
}

String::String(const String& other)
{
    if (str != nullptr)
        delete[] str;
    length = strlen(other.str);
    str = new char[length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        str[i] = other.str[i];

    str[length] = '\0';
}

String::String(String&& other) noexcept
{
    length = other.length;
    str = other.str;
    other.str = nullptr;
}

String::~String()
{
    delete[] str;
}

void String::show()
{
    cout << str;
}

size_t String::Length() 
{
    return length;
}

bool operator== (const String& str, const String& other)
{
    if (str.length != other.length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != other.str[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool operator!= (const String& str, const String& other)
{
    return !(operator==(str, other));
}

char& String::operator[] (size_t i) const
{
    return str[i];
}

String& String::operator= (const String& other)
{
    if (this->str != nullptr)
        delete[] str;
    length = strlen(other.str);
    this->str = new char[length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        this->str[i] = other.str[i];

    this->str[length] = '\0';

    return *this;
}
String& String::operator+ (const String& other)
{
    String newStr;
    length = strlen(str) + strlen(other.str);
    newStr.str = new char[length + 1];

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < strlen(str); i++)
        newStr.str[i] = str[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(other.str); i++, j++)
        newStr.str[i] = other.str[j];

    newStr[length] = '\0';

    return newStr;
}
```

Скрины с описанием ошибки:

1
[image: 1]
2
[image: 2]

Comment: Помимо ответов: 1) operator+ возвращает ссылку на локальный обьект. Не делайте так. 2) operator[] обьявлен как const а возвращает ссылку на char. 3) operator>> пытается записать в other, который const String&

Comment: @Not Bjarne Stroustrup,  логических ошибок в коде много, не только эти...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan доброго времени суток, можно поподробнее насчет логических ошибок? Пытаюсь разобраться в этой теме, дельные советы были бы кстати

Comment: И еще совет. Не обьявляйте аргументы методов с такими же именами как у членов класа, потому что получите код вроде str[i] = str[i]

Comment: В конструкторе копирования не нужна проверка на nullptr, а operator= нуждается в другой "жизненноважной" проверке. И что будет, если мы создадим строку конструктором по умолчанию и попытаемся ее вывести на экран? Думаю, лучше хранить пустую строку, чем nullptr.

Comment: @Maria White,  В операторе  operator>> аргументом должны быть  istream& и  String&, а у вас  ostream&  и const String& .    Перемещающий конструктор не перемещает, а копирует .  Нет перегруженного неконстантного оператора [], чтобы позволить его применение для записи, а константный должен возвращать  не ссылльку, а копию и  его аргументом должен быть  const  size_t i.  . И operator=  не выполняет проверку совпадения адресов. и если размер str  равен размера массива копируемого обьекта, то  зачем  выделять новую память?... И есть повод для просто замечаний( что лишнее и как было бы луше..)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan не могу понять, что не так с конструктором перемещения

Comment: @Maria White, инициализируйте члены инициализатором конструктора, присваиванием в теле конструктора  вы получаете копию.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А это влияет на результат? Нужно просто length установить в 0, а так вроде бы нормальный конструктор переноса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь

```
String str("HELLO");
```

`"HELLO"` приводится к типу `const char *`. А конструктора такого у вас нет!

Но вот скажите - в конструкторе

```
String::String(char* str)
{
    length = strlen(str);
    this->str = new char[length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        this->str[i] = str[i];

    this->str[length] = '\0';
}
```

вы разве меняете строку, на которую указывает аргумент `str`? Тогда по какой причине вы объявляете его как `char* str`, а не как `const char* str`, каковым он и является? объявите его как

```
String::String(const char* str)
```

Сразу станет легче жить :) Не экономьте на `const`!

Вот, например:

```
size_t String::Length() 
{
    return length;
}
```

Скажите, эта функция-член меняет объект `String`? Нет? Так почему вы не объявите ее как константную?

```
size_t String::Length() const
{
    return length;
}
```

Comment: Позанудствую: `"HELLO"` это `const char [6]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Каковой неявно приводится к `const char*`, но не к `char*`...

Comment: Это да, но у вас написано "имеет тип"...

Comment: @Harry спасибо огромное за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Строковый литерал `"HELLO"` в языке C++ имеет тип `const char [6]`. Он также может быть неявно преобразован к типу `const char *`.

У вашего класса нет конструкторов, способных принимать аргументы типа `const char [6]` или `const char *`. Об этом вам и говорит компилятор.